# How to run this script in all tabs, except some tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im using this code to set some values depending on a column if the days are <= -4

```
function SetValues(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName("tt");

  var data = responses.getRange(1,1,responses.getLastRow(),responses.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row,i) {

    var date =      row [0];
    var nombre =    row [1];
    var pidePor =   row [2];
    var fechaFin =  row [3];
    var dias =      row [4];

    if (dias <= -4){

      var val = responses.getRange( i + 1, 2).getValue();
      responses.getRange( i + 1, 2).setValue(val);

      var val = responses.getRange( i + 1, 3).getValue();
      responses.getRange( i + 1, 3).setValue(val);

      var val = responses.getRange( i + 1, 4).getValue();
      responses.getRange( i + 1, 4).setValue(val);


    }

  });

}
```

Its working fine in the referenced tab, but what I need is to be able to run it all over my sheets excluding some tabs

Anyone can help me please how to accomplish this ?

I've been trying for hours with no luck on this

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is put it in a wrapper function

```
numberAllTheSheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i=0; i<sheets.length; i++){//Avoids sheets named "sheet one" and "sheet four"
     if sheets[i].getName=="Sheet One") continue;
     if sheets[i].getName=="Sheet Four") continue;
     SetValues(sheets[i]);
     }
```

And then modify set values to:

```
function SetValues(responses){

  var data = responses.getRange(1,1,responses.getLastRow(),responses.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row,i) {

    var date =      row [0];
    var nombre =    row [1];
    var pidePor =   row [2];
    var fechaFin =  row [3];
    var dias =      row [4];

    if (dias <= -4){

      var val = responses.getRange( i + 1, 2).getValue();
      responses.getRange( i + 1, 2).setValue(val);

      var val = responses.getRange( i + 1, 3).getValue();
      responses.getRange( i + 1, 3).setValue(val);

      var val = responses.getRange( i + 1, 4).getValue();
      responses.getRange( i + 1, 4).setValue(val);


    }

  });

}


}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function runSetValuesExceptForSomeSheets(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  var excluded=['Sheet1','Sheet4'];//add names of sheets that are excluded
  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++) {
    if(excluded.indexOf(sheets[i].getName())==-1) {
      var sheet=sheets[i];
      var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++) {
        if(data[i][4]<=4) {
          var valA=sheet.getRange(i + 1,2,1,3).getValues();//This makes no sense
          sheet.getRange(i+1,2,1,3).setValues(valA);//This makes no sense
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```